# Automatic record and playback of software installation

Tags: windows, automation, autoit

I am currently testing windows 10 technical preview.

I would like to be able to automatically reinstall all programs that I am using, everytime I install a new build (in theory it should update ok but I'd prefer a clean install each time).

I have a too big (hundreds!) list of programs that I would like to (re)install (I've only installed a small number from the total that are present in the previous windows version installation), so I'm searching for an automated method.

I have found Autoit but that requires manually writing a script for each installation.

Is there a way to automatically create autoit script like recording my clicks and keypresses then at the end produce the autoit script that should be ready to use without further edits? Or any other way that records my actions, then plays them back intelligently, as in clicking buttons only after they appear?

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done the same thing. You're essentially looking for a Windows package manager.

I suggest you use [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org) in conjunction with [Boxstarter](http://boxstarter.org/)*.

### Chocolatey

Chocolatey provides a database of mainly user-maintained (NuGet) packages. A package provides in turn download and install instructions for a specific software product.
If you want to install VLC, simply install Chocolatey and execute `cinst vlc` on the CLI.

FYI: Most packages pass command line arguments (e.g. "/quiet") to the installer executables in order to suppress required user input.

### Boxstarter

Boxstarter mainly provides a means to manage the installation of multiple Chocolatey packages, including the ability to reboot when necessary.

### Important things to keep in mind

- Some older Chocolatey packages have not been and won't be moderated by Choco devs. There is therefore a very unlikely chance that a Choco package installs viruses or malware.
- There are no Chocolatey packages for some notable software products. Sometimes the reason is simply that no one has yet created one, and sometimes the reason is that it is impossible to create one (think of MS Office: where can you legally download the installer without user input, i.e. license key).
- You can specify any source for a Chocolatey package. It would therefore be possible to create a package on the local HDD, which installs MS Office from its installer, which is stored on the HDD as well.

---

* Disclaimer: I am the co-maintainer of two Chocolatey packages.